# asp.net GridView spitting out invalid HTML

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

I was wondering if there was a way to remove the invalid HTML code that the GridView is spitting out once it's created?

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all"
```

I'd like to remove the cellspacing and rules attribute.

Thank you!

Comment: Interesting and valid question. For what it's worth, most times I find I'm just using a repeater to build a table, then applying [jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/).

Comment: I had started with a repeater but then went with a GridView since I needed paging, had to show/hide certain column, etc... The GridView was simpler.... at the time anyways.

Comment: DataTables has built in filtering, paging, and sorting. Works well/easily for smaller data sources. It also works with larger data sets when you can't return all data at once.

Comment: Hmmmm... I was hoping to avoid jQuery for this. Thanks for you're help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can remove the rules="all" by changing the settings of GridLines property of the GridView.

Thank you

Comment: i looked on it but the default value is there as 0. in my opinion it cannot be removed. do u want to change the values?

Comment: @ felix - I just put GridLines="None" and it removed the deprecated rules attribute from the HTML.

Answer (score 5):

Just found that putting

```
<asp:GridView CellSpacing="-1"
```

removes the unwanted and deprecated cellspacing attribute.